# Sql Compact as Embedded Resource or Content in XAP

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-7.1

I want to deploy the .XAP file with SQL CE to windows device. What should I do to make it inclusive in XAP file? Do I have to make it "Embedded Resource" or "Content"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use content. Setting the database file to Embedded Resource will add it to your DLL, which will impact your app's launch time (assuming the DLL is in your startup path) and will bloat your app's memory usage.

If you want to copy the database file to your isolated storage to enable read/write, you can use the code shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286411%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for WP7.x or the following (simpler) code for WP8.x:

```
var dbFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///myDb.sdf"));
await dbFile.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "myDb.sdf", NameCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
```

Comment: So, there isn't a need for a database deployment project in WP8.x as in WP7.x?

Comment: By "database deployment project", are you referring to a project that is solely dedicated to creating the reference DB file? That's a question of how to create the DB, not how to deploy it. But on that front, no - the guidance has not changed since WP7.x. Creating the DB using a phone project is still the most robust approach.

Answer (score 0):

It depends:

If you want to make the database file readable, include as Embedded Resource, and extract to Isolated Storage and use a connection string like:

```
Data Source=isostore:/Chinook.sdf
```

If you want to use the database as readonly, include as content, and use a connection string like:

```
Data Source=appdata:/Chinook.sdf;File Mode=Read Only;
```

More details in my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/01/windows-phone-local-database-tip.html